# No Sound with a Fresh Ubuntu 10.04 Install

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, audio

I finally upgraded from Ubuntu 9.10 to 10.04 and I'm having some trouble getting sound running again.

I have a bgears b-Enspirer sound card that uses the C-Media CMI8788 chip set.  After installing I tried some trouble shooting tips listed at **help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting** with no joy.  I did notice that `aplay -l` did not list my sound card, however, `sudo aplay -l` did.  I added myself to the audio group, which corrected that problem, but I still can't get sound working.

The system seems to detect the card, but when I go to System -> Preferences -> Sound, nothing is listed under Hardware.

The results of `alsa-info.sh` are listed at http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=e884011c5c77f36782e4b61801a17a9bef4e8d64

Any pointers would be great.a

Comment: Have you run an update?

Comment: Yeah, ran the update before I started messing with anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After noticing restart/shutdown was knocking me out to the login screen, I did some digging into that issue and discovered that the NVidia driver breaks many things in Ubuntu 10.04.  Since I had already started a new, clean install I left the default video driver and everything (including sound) is happy.  Looks like it was the NVidia driver.